# Merging two nodes in a directed graph with transitions

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory, transition-matrix

Let's say I have $M=\begin{bmatrix}1&2&1\\ 4&2&0 \\ 1& 1& 1\end{bmatrix}$, a $3\times3$ matrix which is the transition matrix or adjacency matrix of a $3$-node graph.

I would like to merge node $1$ and $2$ into a new $12$ node, and thus only have a $2$-node graph but (there will be loss of info of course) that graph will represent the same "population" dynamics.

Gut feeling would be to weight transitions OUT OF $1$ and $2$ by their relative abundance ($38.1$% and $61.9$% in that case) and to add the transitions TO $1$ and $2$.  In that case I would get $\begin{bmatrix}4,67&1 \\ 1&1\end{bmatrix}$.

And indeed I can see that then the growth rate (max eigenvalue) is the same for both graphs. That the abundance (right eigenvector) or stable-age-population are the same too.

However left (or left*right) eigenvector are different, and more importantly from an interpretation standpoint:  the sensitivity of growth rate to say the transition of node $3$ to node $3$.  (The only unchanged number in my graph/matrix) is different ($0.075$ vs $0.069$.)

Those graphs are not really "equivalent" or "similar" then?

Any idea of how to improve that? Another way of merging those $2$ nodes, whilst (not artificially) keeping the sensitivity to $M_{3,3}$?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Here's a [handy guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to mark up math nicely on this site.  I've marked up the math in your questions - please check that I haven't broken anything, particularly the $2\times2$ matrix :-).

Comment: You write "However left (or left*right) eigenvector are different...". Won't every 3-vector be different from every 2-vector?

Comment: Hi Lee, I mean different once you have summed the first 2 terms, i.e. there are equivalent as they represent the same population dynamics, one where state 1 and 2 are kept separate and one where they are merged.

Comment: Thanks for the guide Frentos